# How can I get product alt text or image caption on detail page outside media gallery?

Tags: magento2

I want to get product Alt text on detail page outside media gallery. I enable caption from **view.xml** and it works. But it displaying on product image. I want to display it outsite media gallery or after product title.

[image]

[image]